# Removing event handler from Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

There's a page that has a hover event defined inside the page script as such:

```
$(".post.fade").hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass("over");
},function () {
    $(this).removeClass("over");
});
```

I want to remove that handler because it's annoying. However, although `$(".post.fade").unbind();` works from inside the Firebug console, it doesn't from Greasemonekey. I'm sure jQuery is loaded properly because `$(".post.fade").remove():` does work.

I suppose Greasemonkey doesn't have access to the page's event handlers or something. I tried unsafeWindow but it still doesn't work.

Is there any way?

EDIT:

Apparently, the solution was to put the code inside `$(document).ready()`. Not sure why, though. And yes, the unsafeWindow is still required.

Comment: This is probably a stupid question, but you've chucked .unbind() inside the jQuery document ready function yeah?

Comment: @Christian Varga: No I hadn't, and now that I have, it works, but only with unsafeWindow. Why is that? I thought Greasemonkey fires on "DOM ready" anyway? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72090/how-to-implement-dom-ready-event-in-a-greasemonkey-script Or is that different from "ready"?

Comment: My guess is that greasemonkey fires on DOM ready, but still before jQuery document ready. Thus the unbind is called before the bind. I could be wrong though :p

Comment: Can you please move your solution down to an answer so we can get this off the Unanswered list?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the solution was to put the code inside $(document).ready(). Not sure why, though. And yes, the unsafeWindow is still required.